# Python: Access variable from subclass in non-overwritten method of superclass

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to access a self variable, which is set in the constructor of a subclass, from a method in the super class.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "I'm the class A."

    def getA(self):
        return self.a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.a = "I'm the class B."

x = B()
print(x.getA())
```

The result is always "A". Why can I not overwrite super variables in the sub class constructor? I'm new to inheritence in Python, I think in Java it works just like I tried.

Edit: Okay, thanks for your comments. As you are right of course, this indeed works. This was just a short sketch to demonstrate, what I was trying to do. The original code was more complex and I missed some selfs. Still a little confusing for me, that you have to write self each time as it's not necessary in Java.

Comment: Other than missing a `self` passed to `getA`, I think your code works as you expect it to... (It prints "I'm the class B").

Comment: As mentioned, the code you posted doesn't work. it should be `def getA(self):`. Please fix that and then run your sample. It prints `I'm the class B.`. We copy/paste to test so you can too!

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue this correctly outputs "I'm the class B." as it should and yes you can overwrite variables in the subclass.

Moreover, `def getA()` should be `def getA(self)`.

For `super` you can use it as you have but it's simpler to just to do `super().__init__()` if on Python 3.x. Similarly, if on 3.x don't need `object` if these are new style classes (depending on Python version).

Comment: Your `super` comment should be prefaced that you can leave off the arguments _if_ OP is working with python3.x.  Since this question isn't tagged one way or the other, I'm not sure you can _assume_ that OP isn't using python2.7 (though we _can_ hope) :-)

Comment: Fair point edited.